# Remove cell duplicates in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with huge amount of data. For example I have 2 columns with data (10k each) and I need to find and remove the duplicates in one of the columns. Highlighting the duplicates is easy but I would like to find a way (formula or VBA) that performs that for me in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find a faster method than the VBA version of Data ► Data Tools ► Remove Duplicates.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("E:E").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
```

Post back if you have an earlier version of Excel.